# Rabbit listener vs Rabbit template in retry properites

Tags: java, spring, spring-rabbit

We are doing retry operation for business exception and storing message after some attempts by using **MessageRecoverer**, so we had the first configuration in XML for retries like max attempt and interval, etc. so after refereed common properties for retry in this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#%20RABBIT
now changed to the properties file

**spring.rabbitmq.listener**  it asynchronous and it had a lot of features like stateless and concurrency

**spring.rabbitmq.template** its synchronous

But both are doing the same operation except asynchronous and synchronous one more question. Kindly correct me if I am wrong and which one have the more efficient way like in performance.

**updated post**

if we are getting  exception based on retry has to perform like

1) if business exception occurs  retry for 3 times

2) if runtime exception** occurs  retry for 1 time

3) Then have to recover by messagerecover and store exception

main class

```
public class Main {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd">

    <!-- Spring configuration -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.rabbit.first.*" />
    <context:mbean-export default-domain="com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter" />

    <!-- RabbitMQ common configuration -->

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        username="guest" password="guest" port="5672" virtual-host="/" host="localhost" />


    <!-- <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/> -->
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <!-- Queues -->

    <!-- <rabbit:queue id="springQueue" name="spring.queue" -->
    <!-- auto-delete="true" durable="false" /> -->

    <rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" advice-chain="retryAdvice">
        <rabbit:listener queues="BBBqueue" ref="messageListener" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" advice-chain="retryAdvice">
        <rabbit:listener queues="DDDqueue" ref="messageListener" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter.MessageHandler" />

    <bean id="retryAdvice"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
        <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" />
        <property name="retryOperations" ref="retrytest" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"
        class="com.spring.rabbit.first.deadletter.AutoConfiguringRepublishMessageRecoverer" />
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="amqpTemplate" </constructor-arg> -->
    <!-- <constructor-arg name="errorTemplate" value="test"</constructor-arg> -->
    <!-- </bean> -->


    <!-- <bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate"> 
        <property name="backOffPolicy"> -->
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy"> -->
    <!-- <property name="initialInterval" value="2000" /> -->
    <!-- <property name="multiplier" value="10.0" /> -->
    <!-- <property name="maxInterval" value="30000" /> -->
    <!-- </bean> -->
    <!-- </property> -->
    <!-- <property name="retryPolicy"> -->
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy"> -->
    <!-- <property name="retry" value="retrytest" /> -->
    <!-- </bean> -->
    <!-- </property> <property name="retryPolicy" ref="retrytest"></property> 
        </bean> -->

    <bean id="retrytest" class="com.spring.rabbit.first.retry.RetryOperationTest" />


    <rabbit:topic-exchange name="AAAqexchnage">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="BBBqueue" pattern="" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>

    <rabbit:queue name="BBBqueue"></rabbit:queue>

    <rabbit:topic-exchange name="CCCexchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="DDDqueue" pattern="" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>

    <rabbit:queue name="DDDqueue"></rabbit:queue>

</beans>
```

message handler

```
public class MessageHandler implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        System.out.println("Text: " + new String(message.getBody()));


        if(message!=null)
        {
        message = null;
        if (message == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        }


    }
}




@Configuration
public class RetryOperationTest {

     @Bean
      public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        final RetryTemplate ret = new RetryTemplate();
        ret.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
        return ret;
      }

      @Bean
      public RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
        final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>() {{
            put(RuntimeException.class, true);
          }
        };
        final RetryPolicy ret = new SimpleRetryPolicy(1, map, true);
        return ret;
      }

}
```

am getting error after debug like

```
00:33:41.233 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'retryAdvice' while setting bean property 'adviceChain'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retryAdvice' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.spring.rabbit.first.retry.RetryOperationTest$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$649b8c8] to required type [org.springframework.retry.RetryOperations] for property 'retryOperations'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.spring.rabbit.first.retry.RetryOperationTest$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$649b8c8] to required type [org.springframework.retry.RetryOperations] for property 'retryOperations': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear.

> But both are doing the same operation except asynchronous and synchronous

That is not true; the listener can only receive messages (message-driven), the template can send or receive (poll for) messages.

When receiving, message-driven is generally more efficient; polling would typically only be used for on-demand message-reception.

For more sophistication with retry (such as customizing the message recoverer, configuring the `RetryTemplate` to have conditional retries based on the exception types, you need to define the beans (`RabbitTemplate`, `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` yourself rather than using Spring Boot's default beans.

Comment: Thx for information is there any doc or sample reference  for conditional retries

Comment: I am using rabbit template for sending message but for retry am using listener its working fine whether we can use like that??

Comment: See [the javadocs for `SimpleRetryPolicy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/index.html?org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.html) which is injected into the retry template - you provided it with a map of exceptions and behavior - e.g. `...RuntimeException:true, ...MyFooException:false`.

Comment: i updated post with simpleretrypolicy example but its not reaching this class after exception how to achieve both exception kindly help on this.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - you need to show more of your configuration and explain exactly what is not behaving as you expect.

Comment: It looks like you are injecting a bean `retrytest` which is a `RetryOperationTest` not a `RetryTemplate` - you need to inject the bean called `retryTemplate` from that configuration class.